# Why are my localized variables showing up as numbers?

Tags: swift, localization, translation, localizable.strings

So, I'm translating my app to another language. I have a few texts with variables interpolated, example:

```
label.text = String(format: NSLocalizedString("Your name is %d", comment: "label that show user's name"), name)
```

Now, I go to Localizable.strings file and translate it (I won't actually translate it):

```
"Your name is %d" = "Your name is %d"
```

But in my ViewController, the variable **%d** isn't showing up in letters, but in random numbers, like 782393, etc. Why is this happening? One curious thing is that in one text I did the "same thing":

```
anotherLabel.text = String(format: NSLocalizedString("Your name is %d and you have %d assignments", comment: "label that show user's name"), name, someArray.count)
```

When translating:

```
"Your name is %d$1 and you have %d$2 assignments" = "Your name is %d$1 and you have %d$2 assignments"
```

The curious thing is that the second **%d** shows as normal, the number of objects in the array

How it comes this is happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things like `%d` are called format specifiers. They differ depending on what you are trying to print. To print an `int` you use `%d`. To print a C style string you use `%s` and to print an Objective-C string or object you use `%@`.

In your case, you are seeing some random number because you are trying to print a string formatted as an int. Since your `name` variable is probably either an Objective-C or Swift string you should be using `%@` as your format specifier.

You can find a full listing of available specifiers here: [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)